# Log rotation with automatic *.log file discovery

Tags: linux, logrotate

I am hosting several websites which each of run their own Python process and write *.log output files, but the directory structure is not standardized.

Example:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 plone      plone      125M 2012-08-29 11:35 ./x/var/log/instance-Z2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 plone      plone       19M 2012-08-29 00:07 ./zope2.9/y/log/event.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 plone      plone      188M 2012-08-13 00:09 ./zope2.9/y/log/Z2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 plone      plone      137M 2010-11-16 09:41 ./zope2.9/y/log/event.log
```

I'd like to make log rotate autodiscovery these log files and run a log rotation on them, as opposite to manually type in every log file to logrotate conf.

- Does any existing tools offer this kind of log file discovery and rotation capabilities, without manually specifying each file?
- If not... then just write a shell script which generates the logrotate conf?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Python script for performing auto-discovery and generating logrotate conf file:

- http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/08/30/autodiscovering-log-files-for-logrotate/